# Adjacent list self referencing to Graph object

Tags: c++, graph, this

i am trying to implement an adjacent list for a graph class in C++. At the moment I want to write a method which will update the adjacent list of the Graph node and every adjacent node. Could you tell me what is wrong with this snippet of code? When I am executing my program the adjacent nodes still don't have the node calling update_adjacent in their adjacent list.
Thank you in advance.

```
void Graph::update_adjacent(list<Graph>l) {
for (list<Graph>::iterator iterator = l.begin(), end = l.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) {
    adj_list.push_back(*iterator);
    (*iterator).adj_list.push_back(*this);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using automatic storage in your list. This means everytime you do a adj_list.push_back(*iterator) you are copying the object pointed by the iterator in your list (instead of holding a reference to the object pointed by the iterator). On the next line, when you insert *this in the iterator's object adjacency list, the copy you previously stored in this->adj_list gets outdated.
To solve your problem, I suggest you start using unique_ptr<Graph> in place of Graph and thus, change the method argument and the adj_list member attribute from list<Graph> to list<unique_ptr<Graph>>.